# Python 2.6 subprocess.call() appears to be invoking setgid behavior triggering Perl's taint checks. How can I resolve?

Tags: python, perl, subprocess

I've got some strange behavioral differences between Python's subprocess.call() and os.system() that appears to be related to setgid. The difference is causing Perl's taint checks to be invoked when subprocess.call() is used, which creates problems because I do not have the ability to modify all the Perl scripts that would need untaint code added to them.

Example, "process.py"

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, subprocess

print "Python calling os.system"
os.system('perl subprocess.pl true')
print "Python done calling os.system"
print "Python calling subprocess.call"
subprocess.call(['perl', 'subprocess.pl', 'true'])
print "Python done calling subprocess.call"
```

"subprocess.pl"

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "perl subprocess\n";
`$ARGV[0]`;
print "perl subprocess done\n";
```

The output - both runs of subprocess.pl should be the same, but the one run with subprocess.call() gets a taint error:

```
mybox> process.py
Python calling os.system
perl subprocess
perl subprocess done
Python done calling os.system
Python calling subprocess.call
perl subprocess
Insecure dependency in `` while running setgid at subprocess.pl line 4.
Python done calling subprocess.call
mybox>
```

While using os.system() works, I would really rather be using subprocess.check_call() as it's more forward-compatible and has nice checking behaviors.

Any suggestions or documentation that might explain why these two are different? Is it possible this is some strange setting in my local unix environment that is invoking these behaviors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your error is with perl, or the way it's interacting with your environment.
Your backtick process is calling setgid for some reason. The only way I can replicate this, is to setgid on /usr/bin/perl (-rwxr-sr-x). [EDIT] Having python setgid does this too!

[EDIT] I forgot that os.system *is* working for you. I think the only relevant difference here, is that with os.system the environment is *not* inherited by the subprocess. Look through the environment of each subprocess, and you may find your culprit.

Comment: Interesting that you were able to reproduce it that way. I just discovered that if I switch Python to the 2.5.2 that I have installed, the problem goes away. I checked my Perl binary and it does not have the setgid bit set on it. It might be something wrong with the Python install.

Comment: Ah! the setgid bit is set on the 2.6.1 Python binary! Unexpected, but hopefully I can get the sysadmin to fix that and make the problem go away.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't happen for me:

```
$ python proc.py
Python calling os.system
perl subprocess
perl subprocess done
Python done calling os.system
Python calling subprocess.call
perl subprocess
perl subprocess done
Python done calling subprocess.call

$ python --version
Python 2.5.2

$ perl --version
This is perl, v5.8.8 built for i486-linux-gnu-thread-multi
```

What are your version numbers?

Under what sort of account are you running?

EDIT:

Sorry missed the title - I don't have python 2.6 anywhere easy to access, so I'll have to leave this problem.

EDIT:

So it looks like we worked out the problem - sgid on the python 2.6 binary.

It would also be interesting to see if subprocess with the shell also avoids the problem.

Comment: Python 2.6.1 has the problem, 2.5.2 does not appear to have the problem (those are the versions I happen to have installed). The Perl version is a 5.8.5. I'm digging through the "What's new in Python" pages to try and find something related.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention this is a SuSE 9 Linux install (with some tweaks and extra programs from my friendly Engineering Computing department)